# Spring security oauth2 as a resource server and a client

Tags: spring, spring-security

I have a Spring microservice that is a resource server and a client to other APIs.
I use both `spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client` and `spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server`

My configuration is as this :

```
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          myApp:
            authorization-grant-type: client_credentials
            client-id: ${clientId}
            client-secret: ${clientSecret}
        provider:
          myApp:
            token-uri: ${tokenUri}
            authorization-uri: ${author}
security:
  oauth2:
    resourceserver:
      jwt:
        jwk-set-endpoint: /ext/JWKS
        userinfo-endpoint: /idp/userinfo.openid
```

On the client side I want to use a client credentials flow since it's machine to machine while on the resource server side, I can have personal token from the people of my organization.

On the client side, I use a `WebClient` configured with a `ServletOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction`

While investigating a memory leak on my service, I figured out that the `FilterFunction` was using an `InMemoryOAuth2AuthorizedClientService` saving for every personal token, the same machine to machine token : it uses the principal from the resource server request inside the client request that will be emitted.

That is something I do not understand. Is this a legitimate behavior ? In my opinion, we do not need to save the resource server request principal.
Is there some misconfiguration I would have done ?

Thank you